# GCP - AppEngine redirect subdomain traffic to TLD

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, redirect, google-cloud-platform

Application on Google Cloud Platfrom has already been uploaded and accepts all traffic from wild card subdomains.
The site serves fine from subdomains www. for instance but.

I have been tasked to ensure that only the Top Level Domain of the domain is receiving the traffic for analytic purposes.

For instance, www.DOMAIN.com needs to permanently redirect traffic to DOMAIN.COM
The application is .JS

Thank you kindly

Comment: Edit your question and provide details on your web server. Do a Google Search on web server redirection for your web server. There are thousands of articles.

Comment: Could you please share you domain provider information?